# Can likes on Vimeo be traced to their owner?

Tags: vimeo

A professor uploaded his course lessons on Vimeo. I'd like to give him a Like for the much appreciated effort, but I'd rather not let him on the fact I'm watching his lessons while reviewing two days before the exam :D

Can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they have a [Vimeo Plus](http://www.vimeo.com/plus) account they can see who is liking their videos as part of the Advanced Statistics section:

> With Advanced Statistics you can stay on top of all your statistics, look at your weekly, monthly and yearly stats, see where people are watching your videos, **and find people who like or comment on your videos.**

For a normal account, unless they know your account profile and click to your Likes page and search for their video in there, then not really.

Comment: The professor has a Plus account, so I'll forgo that for now :)